# vertical alignment of stacked icons in font awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, fontawesome-4.4.0

I can't manage to vertically align a stacked icon `fa-stack` to a normal icon `fa-fw` in Font awesome 4.7 and bootstrap 3:

```
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dot-circle-o fa-stack-1x text-danger"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o fa-stack-1x text-info"></i>
</span> <strong>Company Ltd.</strong><br>
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i> Street 7<br>
```

I made a jfiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/tjykrv7q/
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5nqc.jpg)

Comment: That's working just fine for me in Firefox on OS X - maybe post an image of what you see, plus your browser and OS.

Comment: thanks - i added a screenshot. The margin or something is too wide at the `fa-stack` i have this effect in ff 50.0.1 and chrome 55.0.2883.75 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like the class "fa-stack" sets an margin of 5px to your Icons..
You can add "marging: -5px" to fix this like:

```
<span class="fa-stack" style="margin: -5px;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tjykrv7q/2/